# Linkify with provided text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm personally not very good with `preg_replace`, and could use some help if possible.

I'd like to linkify a string and allow an optional text parameter. Examples:

> Input: `[[http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext]]`
>
> Output: `<a href="http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext">http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext</a>`

---

> Input: `[[http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext "click here"]]`
>
> Output: `<a href="http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext">click here</a>`

How would I be able to do this (using `preg_replace` if possible)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: lol. I thought it said `liquefy` at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regx, you want to match the [[stuff]], right?

```
 /\[\[(?P<link>[^\s]+)\s(?P<text>[^\]]+)\]\]/
```

https://regex101.com/r/pT4bL1/1

Id help you with the links but don't know how you create them.  For example using preg_match with the 3rd parameter you would have the parts in `[[]]` and then could just do

```
  if( preg_match('/\[\[(?P<link>[^\s]+)\s(?P<text>[^\]]+)\]\]/', '[[http://www.example.com/path/to/file.ext "click here"]]', $match ) ){
      echo '<a href="'.$match['link'].'">'.$match['text'].'</a>';
   }
```

To explain the regx

- `\[\[` - is just the [[
- `(?P<link>[^\s]+)` - `(?P<name>..,)` is named capture group `[^\s]+`anything but a space.
- `\s` a space
- `(?P<text>[^\]]+)` same as above except `[^\]]+` anything but ]
- `\]\]` - the ending ]]

Comment: I used `$output = preg_replace("#\[\[(?P<link>[^\s]+)\s(?P<text>[^\]]+)\]\]#", "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>", $output);` and `$output = preg_replace("#\[\[(?P<link>[^\s]+)\]\]#", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $output);` from your RegEx, thank you so much.

Comment: you can use this regx to match both `\[\[(?P<link>[^\s\]]+)(?:\s(?P<text>[^\]]+))?\]\]`   `(?:\s ... )?` is non capture ( for the space ) and ending `?` is optional.  Then you could do preg match as I showed and check if the second match is set to know which of the two it is.

Comment: Like this link https://regex101.com/r/pT4bL1/2 , dont miss this change too  `[^\s\]]+` not space or `]`

Comment: Weird bug, my bad. Sorry for wasting your time. Fixed.